# How to get all external in db2 using a system tables information

Tags: db2

I need to get complete list of external tables in db2 database. I have defined schema called DB2INST1. How to get complete list of external tables information using system tables?

Comment: Do you want to get just the names or what other metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information lives in `syscat.tables` (documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=views-syscattables))  for Db2-LUW databases that support external tables, which have their PROPERTY column with value Y in position 27 of that column.

Example query returns the fully qualified name of external tables:

```
select trim(tabschema)||'.'||rtrim(tabname)
from syscat.tables
where substr(property,27,1)='Y'
with ur;
```

Comment: Thank you Mao. It will be cool if you provide link for some details in db2 documentation. I googled but did not find. I want to dive  deeply in this topic

Answer (score 0):

In general, the best and most reliable way to retrieve all information and to recreate the DDL statements for tables is to use the [db2look tool](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-db2look-db2-statistics-ddl-extraction-tool). If you want to extract the metadata on your own, there are some catalog views to start with:

- [SYSCAT.TABLES](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=views-syscattables) holds the table information. Look for the PROPERTY column and check there if it is an external table.
- [SYSCAT.COLUMNS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=views-syscatcolumns) has the basic column information. But there are more related tables depending on types and attributes.
- [SYSCAT.EXTERNALTABLEOPTIONS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=views-syscatexternaltableoptions) shows the actual options for an external table, the things in addition to what makes a regular table.

There are many more tables to hold table properties, depending on the complexity of the table and column definitions.

Comment: Thank you Data Henrik This is useful information for me.